# webdriverio report generation issue

Tags: webdriver-io, allure

Please help to generate webdriverio report upon completion of execution, this reports needs to be emailed . Is there any solution available to achieve this requirement ?

PS : I even tried allure report that is not meeting my requirements so pls suggest any other options.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.